# C++: const reference, before vs after type-specifier

Tags: c++, reference, constants

What is the difference between the arguments in:

```
int foo1(const Fred &arg) {
...
}
```

and

```
int foo2(Fred const &arg) {
...
}
```

?
I don't see this case covered in the parashift FAQ.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.8

Comment: is this a question about style? "const Fred" sounds good in english, but "Fred const" looks better to me.

Comment: On a related note, is there any reason one should prefer `Fred const &arg` over `Fred const& arg`? I like the latter better because `const&` is a unit there meaning "constref", and the name `arg` is separated by a blank from all the type specifiers.

Comment: @dehmann: But `int const& ref` doen't mean 'const ref' but 'ref to const'.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640446/why-do-some-people-prefer-t-const-over-const-t

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth link is broken, I believe it moved to here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-alt

Answer (score 144, accepted):

[No difference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-alt) as const is read right-to-left with respect to the &, so both represent a reference to an immutable Fred instance.

`Fred& const` would mean the reference itself is immutable, which is [redundant](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense); when dealing with [const pointers](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ptr-vs-ptr-const) both  `Fred const*` and `Fred* const` are valid but different.

It's a matter of style, but I prefer using `const` as a suffix since it can be applied consistently including [const member functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns).

Comment: Then what is a point to make `std::is_const<const T&>::value` be `false`?

Comment: @abyss.7 that's a reference to `const T`; the reference is mutable.

Comment: How is the reference mutable if, by definition, it cannot be re-bound, and this is exactly what is discussed by this question and the answers to it - the notion of `T& const` being redundant? It was a very valid question about `is_const`, and one I also would like to know the answer to.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe indeed the reference cannot be re-bound so in that sense references are not mutable. It would be better to simply say that references ignore `const` qualifiers on the reference itself: "Reference types cannot be cv-qualified at the top level; there is no syntax for that in declaration, and if a qualification is added to a typedef-name or decltype specifier, or type template parameter, it is ignored." (See [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference))

Answer (score 167):

### Behavior

There is no semantic difference between `const T&` and `T const&`; the language treats them as the same type. (The same thing applies to `const T*` and `T const*`.)

### As a matter of style

Regarding which you should prefer stylistically, however, I'll dissent from a lot of the other answers and prefer `const T&` (and `const T*`):

- `const T&` is the style used in Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language* book.
- `const T&` is the style used in the C++ standard itself.
- `const T*` is the style used in K&R's *The C Programming Language* book.
- `const T*` is the style used in the C standard.
- Due to the above factors, I think `const T&`/`const T*` have way more inertia than `T const&`/`T const*`. `const T&`/`const T*` empirically seem way more common to me than `T const&`/`T const*` in all of the C++ and C code that I've seen.  I think following common practices is more readable than dogmatically adhering to right-to-left parsing rules.
- With `T const*`, it seems easier to misplace the `*` as `T* const` (especially if people aren't as accustomed to it).  In contrast, `const* T` is not legal syntax.

### What about the right-to-left parsing rule?

Regarding the whole right-to-left parsing argument that people seem to love to use: as I mentioned in a comment to another answer, `const T&` reads fine right-to-left too.  It's a reference to a T constant. "T" and "constant" each can work as an adjective or a noun. (Additionally, reading `T const*` right-to-left can be ambiguous since it could be incorrectly interpreted as "pointer constant *to* T" instead of as "pointer *to* constant T".)

Comment: +1, agreed. When reading code it's easier to spot a const if the line begins with const. The right-left rule is really only needed when manually parsing especially hairy type declarations. Why not optimize for the most common case? Besides, IMHO if you write type declarations so you need to manually run an FSM in your head you're doing it wrong.

Comment: -1. Regardless of how justified your conclusions are and how much I personally agree to them, they are *not answering the asked question* directly. This makes the second-most answer to a simple question appear like an off-topic gibberish about some messy underwater machinery, with no conclusions, no direct answer — nothing. You'll get my upvote when you add a simple clear summary stating "**No, there is no semantic difference between both syntaxes**, but there are some stylistical considerations as follows...". And only then all those bullets.

Comment: IMO the reason `const T&` reads better, is that:
1- We read code from left to right. And 
2- When describing a new concept we start from the more general concept to the more specific.
Here, the `const` keyword is more general as it sections the variable space into two categories, whereas the type specifier sections it into many.

Comment: "pointer to" should stay together. So there is no ambiguity for `T const*`

Comment: @Dexter While "pointer to" *should* stay together, it's another thing to remember and potentially get wrong.

Comment: @jamesdlin what is there exactly to remember? You read it left to right, as it is written. `pointer to const T`. Meanwhile `const T*` has something to remember, the fact that const, if there's nothing on the left, applies to the right, and now tell me, is it constant pointer to T, or is it constant T? How far to the right does const extend to? Why does it go left to right in the first place, against everything else? If we go backwards, then we go backwards all the way. Otherwise you have something to actually remember, because its not as obvious as just reversing a direction.

Comment: @Sahsahae Huh? 1. `T const*` is *not* read left-to-right as written. You have to read it right-to-left, and as I already explained, you have to remember that it's "pointer to constant T" and not "pointer constant to T". 2.Regarding your "meanwhile" remark, as I *also* already explained in my answer, you *do* read `const T*` right-to-left (i.e., "backwards all the way"): "pointer to T constant".

Comment: @jamesdlin you don't have to remember anything, you literally only need to connect `* -> const -> T`. That's what reading right to left means. If you mean you have to ***unlearn*** that const associates with right instead of left sometimes, well that's the problem of the opposite way of writing it, which is what causes const to apply to the right, because there's nothing on the left `const T*`, that's why they're unambiguously equal, except harder to grok to people who don't know the rules. and fail to read this whether they read from left or from right. C++ is read right to left otherwise...

Answer (score 14):

Though they are one and the same, to retain consistency with the [RIGHT-LEFT](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) rule about parsing C and C++ declarations, it is better to write `Fred const &arg`

Also refer [this](http://www.dansaks.com/articles/1999-02%20const%20T%20vs%20T%20const.pdf) for developing more understanding about declarations, qualifiers and declarators.

Comment: I prefer the suffix, because it works better with `typedef` expansion. Example: `typedef int* pointer;`, `const pointer` **is not** `const int*`, it's `int* const`. The suffix form is not awkward.

Comment: IMO `const T&` reads fine right-to-left too; it's a reference to a T constant.  `T` and `constant` each can work as an adjective or a noun.

Answer (score 8):

Both work, and [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constplacement) is the explanation from the man who wrote it.
To quote him:

> Why? When I invented "const"
>   (initially named "readonly" and had a
>   corresponding "writeonly"), I allowed
>   it to go before or after the type
>   because I could do so without
>   ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

No difference, [both are syntactically and semantically same.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.8)

Answer (score 4):

References doesn't work the same way as pointers: for pointers you can have 'const pointers' (`type * const p`) and 'pointer to const' (`const type * p` or `type const * p`).

But you don't have this for references: a reference will always refer to the same object; in that sense you can consider that 'references' are 'const references' (the same way you can have 'const pointers').

Therefore something like 'type & const ref' is not legal. You can only have 'reference to type' (`type &ref`) and 'reference to constant type' (`const type &ref` or `type const &ref`; both are exactly equivalent).

One last thing: even if `const type` sounds more correct in English, writing `type const` allows a more systematic understanding of declarations "right to left" : `int const & ref` can be read has 'ref is a reference to a constant int'. Or more complicated example: `int const * const & ref`, ref is a reference to a constant pointer to a constant int.

Conclusion: in your question, both are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

No difference
http://c-faq.com/ansi/constptrconst.html