# How to use vectors with reference objects

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013

```
addWidget(const Widget& nWidget){
Widgets.push_back(nWidget);
```

i am trying to send an object from a x* by ref in to a vector holding  and i get the following error

```
    1   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=Widget *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Widget *>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (const Widget *)
        object type is: std::vector<Widget *, std::allocator<Widget *>>
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Show your declaration of Widgets. It should probably be `std::vector<const Widget&>` and not whatever you have.

Comment: vector<Widget*> Widgets; (the basic form was Char ** Widgets) but we were allowed to use <vector>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message it appears that `Widgets` is an `std::vector<Widget *>`.  If that is the case, then you could make the code work simply by taking a pointer to `nWidget`:

```
Widgets.push_back(&nWidget);
```

As well as by changing `Widgets` to `std::vector<Widget const *>`, or changing the argument to `Widget &` (remove the `const`) -- taking a pointer to a `Widget const &` results in a `Widget const *` so you would get an error that you are discarding const qualifiers.

Comment: the name of the func must be "addWidget(const Widget& nWidget)" we are not allowed to change it i tryed to use "Widgets.push_back(&nWidget);" but i still get an error
apparently adding vector < CONST widget*> solved the error, but in this case i wont be able to change any values in the widget it self one its stored in an array or am i mistaken?

Comment: @SoNiC306 Because the `const`-ness is different.  If you can't change the signature of the function then you must change the vector to `std::vector<Widget const *>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer just one more thing ... what is the difference from "const widgets *" to "widget const *" - its blurry to me

Comment: @SoNiC306 [They mean the same thing.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3694630/501250)  I prefer `T const *` over `const T *` because in C++ you read from right to left, and `T const *` is more consistent.  For example, `T const * const` is read right to left as "constant pointer to constant T."  `const T * const` muddies the waters a bit: "constant pointer to a T... that is constant."  If you always put `const` immediately following the thing you want to be constant, there is never any potential ambiguity.