# Copy ctor and copy assignment operator const keyword position

Tags: c++

I've recently noticed that the const keyword on some code examples shifted in the middle (from respectable blog sites), something like this:

```
X(X const& that) { .../... }

X& operator=(X const& other) { .../... }
```

Is this equivalent to this more familiar syntax?

```
X(const X& that) { .../... }

X& operator=(const X& other) { .../... }
```

What is the purpose of switching 'const' that way?

Comment: They are equivalent. It's simply a matter of taste.

Comment: Relevant: [C++: const reference, before vs after type-specifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It doesn't matter where to put `const`: `const int & == int const &`

2) Why? It is mnemonic rule.

`int * const` - constant pointer (`const` **after** *)

`int const *` - pointer to the constant value (`const` **after** int).

So, its for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this equivalent to this more familiar syntax?

Yes, both syntaxes here are equivalent.

```
X(X const& x)
X(const X& x)
```

This says that `x` aliases an object of type `X`, but that the object cannot be changed *using* `x`. (It can still be modified if you use some non-`const` alias, pointer, etc.)

You should read it from right-to-left: `x` is an alias (or reference) to an object of type `X` that is `const`.

I'd also recommend reading [C++ FAQ: Const Correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)