# Cannot bind lvalue to A<Cv2>&&

Tags: c++, constants, universal-reference

I thought universal reference (`T&&`) is supposed to take any kind of reference. But the following doesn't work.

I run into this problem when I try to be const-correct in a library that I am writing. I am new to C++ and haven't seen something like this before.

test.cpp:

```
enum Cv_qualifier {
    constant,
    non_const
};
template <Cv_qualifier Cv> class A;
template<>
class A<Cv_qualifier::constant> {
public:
    template<Cv_qualifier Cv2> 
    void t(const A<Cv2>&& out) {}
};

template <>
class A<Cv_qualifier::non_const> {
public:
    template<Cv_qualifier Cv2> 
    void t(const A<Cv2>&& out) {}
};

int main()
{
    A<Cv_qualifier::non_const> a;
    A<Cv_qualifier::constant> b;
    a.t(b);
}
```

Error (compiled with `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11`):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:24:10: error: cannot bind ‘A<(Cv_qualifier)0u>’ lvalue to ‘const A<(Cv_qualifier)0u>&&’
     a.t(b);
          ^
test.cpp:17:10: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void A<(Cv_qualifier)1u>::t(const A<Cv2>&&) [with Cv_qualifier Cv2 = (Cv_qualifier)0u]’
     void t(const A<Cv2>&& out) {}
          ^
```

By the way, in the actual program, the `class A` does not own any actual data, and contain references to another class that actually hold the data. I hope this means I am not constantly create indirection/copy data when I allow the member function `t` of `class A` to accept temporary objects.

Comment: You are not using universal references.  && is not a universal reference, it's an rvalue reference.  T&& is when T is a template parameter deduced by the type it's called with.  In other words, T has to be a template parameter and a parameter to the function AND T has to be deduced, not specified.

Comment: So something like `std::vector<T>&&` or `class_name<Template parameters>&&` are not universal references? And the only way to write a universal reference is `T&&`? I thought the `Cv_2` template parameter of the `t` member function has to be deduced.

Comment: If I want an argument that can accept both l-value and r-value reference to a specific class instead of kinds of classes. Is that possible?

Comment: @rxu You can use SFINAE to limit what T can be deduced as.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to figure this out for a whole day. So `T&&` is the only way to make an argument that accepts both l-value and r-value references.

Comment: *"So something like std::vector<T>&& or class_name<Template parameters>&& are not universal references?"* You are right. Universal reference only happen when the compiler can do reference collapsing.

Comment: No, `T&&` is not the only way for a function to accept l-value and r-values.  In your case all you need to do is accept `A<Cv2> const&` and it'll accept anything.

Comment: "universal reference" only occurs when the parameter is exactly `T&&`  ,and `T` is a template parameter of the function

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: would a parameter `A<Cv2> const& a` prevent modification of the values of a? ok I get it. So it does limit modification of the values of a. it is a constant reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Universal reference, or forwarding reference, only happen because of reference collapsing. It work that way:

```
T&& & -> T&
T& && -> T&
T&& && -> T&&
```

That way, when you receive `T&&` in a template function, the rvalue reference can collapse to other types of reference depending of the type of `T`. In any other cases, when the collapsing don't happen, `SomeType&&` will stay `SomeType&&` and will be an rvalue reference.

With that said, if you want your function to support forwarding, you can do that:

```
template <Cv_qualifier Cv> struct A;

template<>
struct A<Cv_qualifier::constant> {
    template<typename T> 
    void t(T&& out) {}
};

template <>
struct A<Cv_qualifier::non_const> {
    template<typename T> 
    void t(T&& out) {}
};
```

Indeed, now the collapsing happen. If you want to extract the `Cv_qualifier` value from `T`, you can make yourself a type trait that do that:

```
template<typename>
struct CvValue;

template<Cv_qualifier cv>
struct CvValue<A<cv>> {
    constexpr static Cv_qualifier value = cv;
};
```

Then, inside your function `t`, you can do that:

```
//                   v----- This is a good practice to apply a constraint
template<typename T, std::void_t<decltype(CvValue<std::decay_t<T>>::value)>* = 0> 
auto t(T&& out) {
    constexpr auto cv = CvValue<std::decay_t<T>>::value;

    // do whatever you want with cv
}
```

If you can't use C++17's `std::void_t`, you can implement it like that:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

---

However, if you only want to test if `T` is an `A<...>`, use this:

```
template<typename>
struct is_A : std::false_type {};

template<Cv_qualifier cv>
struct is_A<A<cv>> : std::true_type {};
```

Don't forget, to use it with `std::decay_t`:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_A<std::decay_t<T>>::value>* = 0> 
void t(T&& out) {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It really makes the universal reference thing more clear. For now, I am trying to use a public `typedef` within class A to make `A::Cv_` reports the Cv template parameter or A. I also try to write a `is_A` trait to test if a `typename` is a `class A`.

Comment: To report the template parameter in `A` you must not use a typedef, but a constant declared as such: `constexpr static Cv_qualifier = Cv;`, much like my `CvValue` I'll update my answer to implement the `is_A` trait.

Comment: I seem to need `struct is_A<A<cv>& > : std::true_type {};` as well. It works now : )

Comment: That's because you missed a `std::decay_t`. `T` may resolve to different types of reference, but the type trait don't know about references. You need to use `is_A<std::decay_t<T>>::value`