# Passing reference type as template argument in nested template structure does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, pass-by-reference

I am puzzled, I was designing a template and I found a strange behavior regarding instantiating the template with `T=float&`:

```
// Given an available float f:
float f = 1.0;

// This getter works for T=float&:
template <typename T>
struct test {
  const T get() { return f; }
};

int main() {
  float& f1 = test<float&>().get();
}
```

The first strange thing is that `f1` should be `const float&` for the code to be correct, and thus, I would expect an error, but it works fine.

The second strange thing is on this similar example that reports an error when I would expect it not to:

```
// Given an available float f:
float f = 1.0;

struct State {
  const float& get() { return f; }
};

// This does not work for T=float&:
template <typename T>
struct test2 {
  State state;
  const T get() { return state.get(); }
};

int main() {
  const float& f2 = test2<float&>().get();
}
```

The error reported is this:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'const T test2<T>::get() [with T = float&]':
main.cpp:31:41:   required from here
main.cpp:22:36: error: binding reference of type 'float&' to 'const float' discards qualifiers
   const T get() { return state.get(); }
```

Which is strange, since the second example only declared `const float&` types, not `float&` and not `const float`, so I don't know what is happening.

Maybe templates were not designed to work with references or its a bug on GCC or I am just doing something dumb.

I tested this code using `gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170306` and also on [repl.it](http://repl.it) website using C++11.

Also if its a bug, I would be interested in any available work arounds.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't expect to get a `const float&` since that's a reference to a const float.  When you substitute `T=float&` into `const T` you get `const (float&)` except that I don't think you can actually form a const reference (distinct from a reference to const)

Comment: Uhm, makes sense. So it is not possible to make the function return a `const float&` by feeding it with `T=float&`? Is there a way to simulate that behavior? For the users of my template it would make sense to have it to return sometimes `float` and other times `float&`. The alternative would be to create a second template with a different name to cover both cases.

Comment: `const typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&`, perhaps

Comment: Uhm, it's a nice trick but then the user would not be able to make the function return only `const float` by passing `T=float`. I might end up writing a second template for this case after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be more specialized. I think this gives the behavior you want:

```
template <typename T>
struct test {
    T get() { return f; }
};

template <typename T>
struct test<T&> {
    const T& get() { return f; }
};
```

To test:

```
int main() {      
    const float& f1 = test<float&>().get();
    float& f2 = test<float&>().get(); //Error
    const float& f3 = test<const float&>().get();
    float f4 = std::move(test<float>().get());
}
```

Comment: Nice, it took me some time to understand the specialization but it does exactly what I wanted. Just to confirm if I interpreted right: The specialization will be used only when the argument is a reference, and otherwise it will use the non-specialized version right?

Comment: @VinGarcia Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier) question.

The same thing happens in your cases.

For the first case, our type is `float&`. And in `float & const`, the `const` is redundant. So it will be resolve as `float &` only.

For the second case, what returned by `State::get()` is a reference to a const float value. And the one returned by `test2<float&>::get()` still is `float&`. Now compiler will prevent you from assigning const float to a non-const one.

Comment: You mean "const float value" instead of "const integer value", but I got it, seems correct. Do you know of any idiom to make a function inside a template to return `const float&` or `const float` based on the template argument type? I am thinking or removing the `const` word from inside the template and forcing the user to use type `const float&` or `const float` whenever he wanted to specify the type.

Comment: Yes, i edited the answer. For the idiom, I think @Even young gave the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

For some completeness, here's the solution I would probably go with:

```
template <class T>
struct make_non_modifiable { using type = const T; };
template <class T>
struct make_non_modifiable<T&> { using type = const T &; };
template <class T>
struct make_non_modifiable<T*> { using type = const T *; };

template <typename T>
struct test {
  typename make_non_modifiable<T>::type get() { return f; }
};
```

I didn't try compiling this code so there might be a typo or two.
I usually prefer class template partial specializations over function template specializations because the latter is harder to understand alongside function overloading.

Comment: Very interesting approach, this might make my code a lot shorter, I'll test it.