# In C, does it matter where I put the * in a pointer variable declaration?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, what is the correct syntax for declaring pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280729/in-c-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-declaring-pointers)

When I read C code, I see several ways to write a pointer,like

```
int *p;
char * s;
char * d = &c;
ll_model* model = new_ll_model(n, cc->term); 
double* avg_ll;
```

My questions are:

1. Are there any differences between them?
2. If there are, what are the differences? That is, does the position of white space and the `*` mean something?
3. Which way is the right way to write a pointer, so it is readable to myself and any other person who will read my code

Comment: How exactly are those different to you?

Comment: Sorry I didn't search the questions using the right words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there's no difference between them.

But I prefer this method:

```
int *p;
```

Instead of:

```
int* p;
```

or

```
int * p;
```

The reason is that because if you want to declare a number of `int *` in the same line, it makes more sense to have the `*` next to the identifier instead of the type because that looks cleaner and less confusing. e.g.

```
int *p, *q, *r;
```

is better than:

```
int* p, *q, * r;
```

If you don't like my reasons, make sure you stick to one of them and don't vary the usage.

Comment: Why would I stick to any of your reasons if I don't like them?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think he means stick to one style, not stick to one of his reasons

Comment: Yeah Seth is right...sorry for not phrasing it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally, no. You can read:

```
int *p;
```

as "*the thing pointed to by `p` is an `int`*" and

```
double* avg_ll
```

as "*the type of `avg_ll` is pointer to `double`*." AFAIK, the former is preferred C style and the latter is more prevalent in C++ code.

However, as the [C FAQ explains](http://c-faq.com/decl/charstarws.html), the latter style can lead to mistakes if you are in the habit of declaring multiple variables in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of differences between the lines of code you posted, but none of them are terribly relevant to how you declare a pointer type.

Whitespace does not matter.

What is readable is in the eye of the beholder. I prefer placing a single space character before and after the `*` character(s).

Answer (score 0):

Answers

1. Yes they are different types of pointer because of different types
2. The white space makes no difference - the difference is used in pointer arithmetic. If you increment a char * it move the pointer on by 1 char. If you increment a int * it moves on the pointer by the size of 1 int
3. I prefer char *foo style - but my style is a little old by now