# Pointer C - declaration

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, what is the correct syntax for declaring pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280729/in-c-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-declaring-pointers)

I am fighting with the c language. Pointers are new to me, and I think I am getting closer and closer to understanding them.

I have though one questions.

What is the difference between:

```
int k = 4;
int* pcp = &k;
```

and

```
int k = 4;
int *pcp = &k;
```

I cant seem to find any difference between these declarations of the pointer, is it just syntactical sugar - or is there any difference?

Thanks

Comment: The only difference is where the space is put. Semantically, they're identical.

Comment: It's not "syntactical sugar" ... that's not at all what that term means. And this has nothing to do with pointers ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in those declarations, but there is a difference between the following two declarations:

```
int* p, p2;  // declares a pointer to int and a regular int
```

and:

```
int *p, *p2; // declares two pointers to int
```

that might be hidden by your example.

So I prefer the second declaration.

Comment: That's why it's usually preferred to glue the `*` to the variable name -- `int* p, p2;` is painful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, it is usually preferred to use separate declarations for each pointer, and to glue the '*' to the base type because that's where it belongs.

Answer (score -2):

you can try it out yourself. just type both, printf it and see what happens :P

if i'm not terribly mistaken though, it's the same ;)