# C++ pointer declaration

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, what is the correct syntax for declaring pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280729/in-c-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-declaring-pointers)

In C++ What is the difference between:

```
int* a;
```

and

```
int *a;
```

Is it same?

Comment: Dupe, and nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Those two constructs are identical. `int *a;` is more C style, because it is consistent with the "declaration follows use" rule in C. This rule means that you can read `*a`, and know that it gives you an `int`.

In C++, types get used on their own more often, so `int* a;` is more typical, as it puts the emphasis on they type being `int*`. Conformance to "declaration follows use" is less important in C++, because does not work everywhere anyway (it doesn't work with references, for example).

Note that if you write `int* a, b;` (which is the same as `int *a, b;`), then only `a` is a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same. There is no difference. Also same as

```
int * a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same.  You can put the asterisk (*) anyplace.