# What is the difference between char * x,y,z;char* x,y,z;char (*)x,y,z;?

Tags: c, pointers, char

Okay I am getting lost in these pointers can somebody exactly tell me what is(are) the difference between `char * x,y,z;`, `char* x,y,z;` and `char (*)x,y,z;` ? If you can please provide resources to your answer or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, what is the correct syntax for declaring pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280729/in-c-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-declaring-pointers)

Comment: @ShimulChowdhury: What about the one in parentheses?

Comment: The one in parentheses doesnt compile.
If you meant char (*x)(), it's a function pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two records

```
char * x,y,z; 
char* x,y,z;
```

are identical and equivalent to

```
char *x;
char y;
char z;
```

Take into account that these declarations are equivalent

```
char*x;
char* x;
char * x;
char *x;
```

All them declare variable x as pointer to char.

This record

```
char (*)x,y,z;
```

is invalid and will not be compiled.

I think you mean the following

```
char (*x),y,z;
```

In this case declaration

```
char ( *x );
```

is equivalent to

```
char *x;
```

You may enclose in parentheses a declarator. So the above record you could write like

```
char ( *x ), ( y ), ( z );
```

Comment: Okay so I got it almost but is `char (*) x,y,z;` same as `char *x,y,z` just curious or this too won't compile ?!

Comment: @Disorted Casanøva No, they are no the same. The declarators are  x and *x. You may write *( x ) or ( *x ).

Comment: Okay that means that basically will not compile.

Comment: @Disorted Casanøva In this record ( * )x there are to adjacent declarators (abstract declarator ( * ) and identifier x). You may not place declarators such a way without separating them with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

The first two mean the same thing. They declare x as a pointer to a char, and y and z as char variables. The third one will cause a syntax error and, as @danielfranca pointed out in the comments, will not compile.

Comment: Thanks i'm kinda noob in this game !

Comment: No problem! I was in your shoes just a few months ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking the question, it is probably because you were looking for a shorthand way of declaring x, y and z all to be pointers to characters.

In most cases, you should just be clear about it:

```
char *x, *y, *z;
```

In more complicated situations where you will use it often, you can use a typedef:

```
typedef char *cp_t;
cp_t x, y, z;
```

Comment: POSIX reserves type names ending with `_t` for future use.

Comment: Well you were close enough to my thinking !! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Declare variables in the same way as you're gonna use them.

```
char *x, y, z;
```

`*x` is a char, `y` is a char, `z` is a char. So `x` is a pointer to a char.

```
void f(void), (*g)(void);
```

`f` and `*g` are functions without parameters or return value. So `g` is a pointer to such a function. The parentheses around `*g` are needed because `(void)` binds more tightly than `*`.