# No viable overload error in reversing a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a [linked list](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/), which has the below code.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* current,prev,next;
        prev=NULL;
        current=head;
        while(current!=NULL){
            next=current->next;
            current->next=prev;
            prev=current;
            current=next;
        }
        head=prev;
        return head;
    }
};
```

Everything looks fine to me but i'm getting error as **no viable overloaded '='** next=current->next

I'm curious to know, why this error is coming out to be? kindly looking for help

Comment: `next` is not a pointer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280765/920069

Comment: In `ListNode* current,prev,next;`, only `current` is a pointer to `ListNode` rest all are of type `ListNode`. Use `ListNode *current, *prev, *next;`.

Comment: Close to a typo. `ListNode* current,prev,next;` is the same as `ListNode* current; ListNode prev; ListNode next;`. You want `ListNode* current,*prev,*next;`

Comment: I recommend to follow the C++ Core Guidelines [ES.10: Declare one name (only) per declaration](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-name-one)

Answer (score 3):

`next` and `prev` are not pointers. To make them pointers you need to specify `*` for each variable.

Change

```
ListNode* current,prev,next;
```

to

```
ListNode *current, *prev, *next;
```

Even better, declare variables when you first use them, not before

```
ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode* prev=NULL;
    ListNode* current=head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        ListNode* next=current->next;
        current->next=prev;
        prev=current;
        current=next;
    }
    head=prev;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.