# Unusual pointer declaration

Tags: c, pointers

I've come across the following function declaration:

```
int function_name(uint8_t* input1, int input2)
```

What is the purpose of declaring a pointer in this way? Is it any different from usual:

```
uint8_t *input1
```

Comment: There is no difference. Just a different convention that some people prefer.

Comment: We who do uint8_t* look at the * as part of the type. But it's up to you how you do it. :)

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990726/correct-way-of-declaring-pointer-variables-in-c-c/6990768#6990768

Answer (score 0):

No, whitespace in this location doesn't matter in C.

Comment: Is there any location where it *does* matter (excluding strings)?