# What does the * do in this scenario?:

Tags: c++

```
int year;
int month;
int day;

ADate * date = new ADate(year, month, day);
```

I know it's usually used for pointers but I don't know what it's doing here. Without it that line obviously creates a new ADate with those int variables passed in but I'm not sure what the * does that changes this?

Comment: just a pointer constructed by the new AData.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `operator new` to create variables in C++.  C++ is not Java and not C#.

Comment: Yes, it is usually used for pointers, and this case is no exception. Without it that line won't even compile.

Comment: you are declaring a pointer of type cladd aDate and initializing it on the heap. if you remove it then you are declaring an object of class aDate but you must remove keyword new

Comment: @jaggedSpire I looked online for some info regarding it but unfortunately the first 5 pages are all about pointers.

Comment: The `*` is part of the [pointer declarator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6990726/1460794) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `*`, `date` is declared as a pointer type, which stores the address of a `ADate` object (points to a `ADate` object). Otherwise, `date` would be declared as a `ADate` object type.

The operator `new` returns a pointer. Thus without the `*`, your program wouldn't be successfully compiled.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/