# Unexpected random numbers

Tags: c, loops

I am working on a simple function that, given an input n, returns n Fibonacci's numbers.

```
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int f1, f2, f3 = 1;
    printf("Insert an integer bigger than 0:\n");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    printf("%i", f1);
    while(counter <= n){
            f3 = f1 + f2;
            printf("%i\n", f3);
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
            counter = counter + 1;
    }
    return 0; 
 }
```

Surprisingly, the function returns different results each time I run the program. Furthermore, these numbers are far bigger/smaller than any possible result.

Most likely, I am missing something obvious, but I cannot explain such a behavior.

Comment: `printf("%i", f1);` What do you think the value of `f1` should be at that stage?

Comment: int f1,f2,f3=1   ====> is f1 and f2 intialized ?

Comment: Should not it be 1?

Comment: @Worice Perhaps it *should* be, but it isn't. Arguably C would be a slightly easier language if that is how it works, but you have to deal with the language as it actually exists. In any event, you could always simply declare them uninitialized in one line and write `f1 = f2 = f3 = 1;` in the next.

Comment: @JohnColeman you are right, I will keep it in mind. I did not think that the random numbers could be a consequence of unassigned variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
int f1, f2, f3 = 1;
```

only initialize `f3` to 1, it does not initialize `f1` and `f2`.
You should use this instead:

```
int f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3 = 1;
```

to initialize all three.

Comment: I had only a slightly suspect that the random number could be a consequence of unsigned variables, but I negated the idea. Quite naive. Thanks.

Comment: Or use different statements to declare different variables. This also avoids the `int * a, b;` [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6990726/589924).

Comment: Right, it's always clearer to declare each variable separately. `int f1 = 1; int f2 = 1; int f3 = 1;`