# Doubts in C Pointers

Tags: c

Many seem to be occasionally having these doubts. So posting it here.

What is the difference in below declarations?

```
int* x;
int *x;
```

Are the below declarations same? Is b a pointer in both declarations?

```
int* a, b;
int *a, b;
```

Comment: No difference except visual.

Comment: That's just a matter of style. Apart from that there is no difference.

Comment: `int*x;` is also the same.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: `int * x;` is also the same

Comment: `b` is not a pointer in either declaration - only `a` is declared as a pointer.  Both declarations are parsed as `int (*a), b;`.

Comment: Thank you all for your response

Answer (score 0):

See [Correct way of declaring pointer variables in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990726/correct-way-of-declaring-pointer-variables-in-c-c)

There is no difference.

Please note that

```
int* a, b;
int *a, b;
```

is **NOT** the same as

```
int* a, *b;
int *a, *b;
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate bit more why it is not the same?

Comment: As John Bode said, `int* a, b;` and `int *a, b;` are parsed as `int (*a), b;`.
There is no type `int*`, but the location `a` points to is `int`.