# What is the difference between Node* p and Node *p?

Tags: c++, pointers

In this line of code:

```
Node* insert(Node *head,int data)
```

What is the difference between `Node* insert` and `Node *head`?

Are they both pointers? And which is better?

Comment: Another dupe https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990726/6865932

Comment: You forgot `Node*insert` and `Node * insert`.

Comment: `Node *head` is often the convention used in C, and `Node* head` is often the convention used in C++.  In both C and C++ cases, the compiler doesn't care.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Where you put the whitespace is completely irrelevant. The compiler doesn't care.