# What the difference between these two C-declaration in memory?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, declaration

What is the difference between these two declarations ? How are such variables used in C programs ? Thank you.

---

`char *names[20];`

`[]` takes precedence over `*`, so the interpretation is: `names` is an array of size `20`. Each array element is of type pointer to `char`.

---

`char (*place)[10];`

In case of using parentheses to override the precedence, the `*` is applied first: `place` is a pointer to an array of size `10`. Each array element is of type `char`.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: I think you need to separate the question and answer components for this to be an appropriate fit on this site. Also, is the "embedded" tag appropriate?

Comment: You may want to read this: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: There is a [website](https://cdecl.org/) that is telling you exactly what each declaration does.

Comment: What books did you read about the C programming language? Did you read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some later C standard?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question

Comment: Was it very difficult to add one printf and outputs sizes of both?

Answer (score 1):

[Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

---

```c
char *names[20];
```

Applying the rule, we learn that `names` is a 20-element array of pointers to `char` values.

More clearly, `names` is an array of 20 `char *` pointers. This allocates enough memory for 20 such pointers.

```c
sizeof(names) == sizeof(char*) * 20
```

---

```c
char (*place)[10];
```

Applying the rule, we learn that `place` is a pointer to a 10-element array of `char` values.

More clearly, `place` is a pointer, and it points to an array of 10 `char`. This allocates enough memory for one such pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
char *names[20];
```

declares an array with the name `names` of 20 elements of the type `char *`. It would be better to write it like

```
char * names[20];
```

This declaration

```
char (*place)[10];
```

declares a pointer with the name `place` that points to an array of 10 elements of the type `char`.

Here is a demonstrative program that I hope makes it more clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char * names[20] =
    {
        "Peter", "Bob", "Mary"
    };
    
    for ( char **p = names; *p != NULL; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%s ", *p );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    char city[10] = "Madrid";
    
    char (*place)[10] = &city;
    
    puts( *place );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Peter Bob Mary 
Madrid
```

In this declaration in the above program

```
char * names[20] =
{
    "Peter", "Bob", "Mary"
};
```

three elements of the array are initialized explicitly by addresses of first characters of the string literals used as initializers. All other 17 elements of the array are implicitly initialized as null pointers.

The same program can be rewritten using typedef(s).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char * T1;
typedef char T2[10];

int main(void) 
{
    T1 names[20] =
    {
        "Peter", "Bob", "Mary"
    };
    
    for ( char **p = names; *p != NULL; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%s ", *p );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    T2 city = "Madrid";
    
    T2 *place = &city;
    
    puts( *place );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown for the previous program.

Comment: `"It would be better to write it like char * names[20];"` -- I disagree with this statement, because if you write `char * names[20], cities[20];`, the position of the `*` will be misleading, implying that both `names` and `cities` were of the same type.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel, The statement you posted isn't the statement Vlad recommended. Only your statement is misleading. To that I say, so don't do that!

Comment: @ikegami: My point is that, in my opinion, it is a bad habit to write it that way, because if you later decide to add a second identifier to the declaration, you can easily forget to add a `*` to the second identifier. The danger of this happening is significantly reduced if you write it the "normal" way.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It is just your personal problem that you write a confusing code. It has nothing common with the code I showed. Try to write a clear code.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel, Re "*because if you later decide to add a second identifier to the declaration*", And my point is that this is a problem of your own doing. Just don't do that. ///  Re "*The danger of this happening is significantly reduced if you write it the "normal" way.*", What? Using `char* names[20]` doesn't remove the ambiguity at all! (And before you say that's not the correct way, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990768/589924).)