# Why is the Dereference operator used to declare pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, syntax, declaration

Why is the  `*`  used to declare pointers?

It remove indirection, but doesn't remove any when you declare a pointer like `int *a = &b`, shouldn't it remove the indirection of `&b`?

Comment: That character `*` has a pretty different meaning in an expression versus a declaration. In an expression it's a dereference operator.  In a declaration it's more like a this-is-a-pointer modifier.

Comment: In a declaration, it's not an operator at all.

Comment: Have you thought about why there is no removal of indirection in `42 * 4`?

Comment: You're close, but you're not quite at the intended way to read C declarations: `int *a;` => `int`, `*a` => The expression `*a` produces `int`. Declarations in C were designed to model use like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many symbols in C and C++ are overloaded. That is, their meanings depend on the context where they are used. For example, the symbol `&` can denote the address-of operator and the binary bitwise AND operator.

The symbol `*` used in a declaration denotes a pointer:

```
int b = 10;
int *a = &b,
```

but used in expressions, when applied to a variable of a pointer type, denotes the dereference operator, for example:

```
printf( "%d\n", *a );
```

It also can denote the multiplication operator, for example you can write:

```
printf( "%d\n", b ** a );
```

that is the same as

```
printf( "%d\n", b * *a );
```

Similarly, the pair of square braces can be used in a declaration of an array, like:

```
int a[10];
```

and as the subscript operator:

```
a[5] = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have a pointer declaration with initialization like this:

```
type *x = expr;
```

it is equivalent to the separate initialization followed by assignment:

```
type *x;
x = expr;
```

It is **not** equivalent to

```
type *x;
*x = expr;      /* WRONG */
```

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the declaration, so it's not a dereference operator at all. Yet it still means the same thing.

```c
int *a
```

can be read as

> The value pointed by `a` is an `int`.

just like

```c
printf("%d\n", *a);
```

can be read as

> Print the value pointed by `a`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990768/589924) to *Correct way of declaring pointer variables in C/C++* for a bit on background on this.

Comment: It actually “is” a dereference operator. Not in the sense that a dereference operation is performed, but in that it still holds its dereference meaning. As K&R explain, a declarator presents a picture of how an identifier will be used. `int *a` says `*a` will be used as an `int`, meaning that when the dereference operator is applied to `a`, the result has type `int`. So the `*` in `int *a` is the dereference operator, but just used for its meaning, not to perform its computation.

Comment: It actually isn't a dereference operator. You can't place an expression on the left of `=` in a declaration. But it does *act as* a dereference, yes, which is what my answer already says.

Answer (score 1):

Back when C was invented, a somewhat interesting choice was made.  Variables would be declared in a kind of echo of how they would be used.

So

```
int a;
```

means "you can get an `int` out of `a`.  Then,

```
int *a;
```

means you can get an `int` out of `*a`.

And,

```
int a[3];
```

means you can get an `int` out of `a[index]`; here, the size is put in where the index would be.

This can be chained to complex cases

```
int *a[3];
```

vs

```
int (*a)[3];
```

now if you don't know how C parsing works, this is opaque; but at least you only have to learn it once!

This is why some people think `int* a` is bad form, because the `*` is really attached to `a` not the `int`.

Initialization of the named variable is a different thing.

```
(some declaration) = (some expression)
```

the symbols in the declaration never act as expressions.  They are the same symbols, just different meaning.