# Pointer declaration in C, whats the difference?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I thought #1

```
uint8_t* start_ptr, end_ptr;
```

and #2

```
uint8_t* start_ptr;
uint8_t* end_ptr;
```

are generally the same. It seems to me they are not.
Could somebody specify what the first one does other than the second?

What happened:

```
          if(strncmp(mseq,mseq_a,8) == 0){
              start_ptr = MY_UART_RingBuffer_getReadPointer();
              start_found = 1;

          }

          if(strncmp(mseq+3,mseq_z,5) == 0){
              end_ptr = MY_UART_RingBuffer_getReadPointer();

              if (start_found == 1){
                  if(!MY_UART_RingBuffer_getOverlap()){
                    end_ptr = end_ptr - 6;
                  }
                  else{
                      start_found = 0;
                      continue;
                  }

                ptrdiff_t length = end_ptr - start_ptr;
                  start_found = 0;
              }
          }
```

On using #1 the compiler will give me this for the length calculation:

```
../Core/Src/main.c:143:32: error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}')
     ptrdiff_t length = end_ptr - start_ptr;
```

On using #2 everything works out fine.

I am somehow confused here. I see the solution but I don't really get the issue.

Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: `uint8_t* start_ptr, end_ptr;` declares `end_ptr` as a `uint8_t`, not a pointer. I expect this is a dupe question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990726/correct-way-of-declaring-pointer-variables-in-c-c

Comment: `On using #2 everything works out fine.` A **major** reason to always use style 2!  :-)

Comment: I find that rather unintuitive. Is there a special reason why C behaves that way? I mean the line basically says "make this and this and this a uint8_t*. There must be a good reason? :-D Thx

Comment: Ah got the problem with Mats answer! stupid of me, thanks !

Comment: @nEmai - There is a reason, but not a good one. The designer of C later regretted the attempt to make the declarations mimic the use of the variable. `int *p` means `*p` is an int. `int q` means `q` is an int. Now try `int *p, q;`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grammatically, the type `uint8_t` is a *declaration-specifier*; whereas the pointer `*` is a *declarator*. [According to C's grammar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) *declarators* bind to the declared name rather than the *declaration-specifier*. Consequently your first line is parsed like:

```
uint8_t (*start_ptr), end_ptr;
```

i.e. only the first name becomes a pointer.

This is one reason some tend to put the space before the pointer `*` rather than after. The correct way to declare those in one line would be:

```
uint8_t *start_ptr, *end_ptr; // both are pointers to uint8_t.
```

Answer (score 2):

Declarations in C consist of two main parts - a sequence of *declaration specifiers* followed by a comma-separated list of *declarators*.  Pointer-ness, array-ness, and function-ness are specified as part of the declarator, so your declaration is being interpreted as

```
uint8_t (*start_ptr), end_ptr;
```

and only `start_ptr` is declared as a pointer.

The idea is that the structure of the declarator match the structure of an expression in the code.  When you want to access the `uint8_t` value pointed to by `start_ptr`, you dereference it with the unary `*` operator:

```
x = *start_ptr;
```

The type of the *expression* `*start_ptr` is `uint8_t`, so the declaration is written as

```
uint8_t *start_ptr;
```

Whitespace is not significant except to distinguish tokens of the same type.  Since `*` cannot be part of any identifier, you can write that declaration as any of

```
uint8_t *start_ptr;
uint8_t* start_ptr;
uint8_t*start_ptr;
uint8_t     *    start_ptr   ;
```

but it will always be tokenized as `uint8_t`, `*`, `start_ptr`, `;`, and parsed as

```
uint8_t (*start_ptr);
```

So if you want to declare both `start_ptr` and `end_ptr` as pointers, then you will need to write either

```
uint8_t *start_ptr, *end_ptr;
```

or

```
uint8_t *start_ptr;
uint8_t *end_ptr;
```

Put another way, we declare pointers as

```
T *p, *q;
```

for the exact same reason we *don’t* declare arrays as

```
T[N] a, b;
```

because the operands of the postfix `[]` subscript operator are `a` and `b`, not `T`, and the operands of the *unary* (hint hint hint) `*` operator are `p` and `q`, not `T`.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
uint8_t* start_ptr, end_ptr;
```

may be equivalently rewritten like

```
uint8_t ( * start_ptr ), ( end_ptr );
```

So there is declared the pointer `start_ptr` of the type `uint8_t *` and the variable `end_ptr` of the type `uint8_t`.

If you want to declare two pointers you have to write

```
uint8_t *start_ptr, *end_ptr;
```

Another approach is to introduce a new type specifier using a typedef declaration  like for example

```
typedef uint8_t * uint8_t_ptr;
```

Using the declared typedef name you can write

```
uint8_t_ptr start_ptr, end_ptr;
```

In this case the both declared variables will have the pointer type `uint8_t *`.

Comment: `Another approach is to introduce a new type specifier using a typedef` never hide pointers. Very bad.

Comment: @0___________ There is provided an example with the typedef to show how declarations can be interpreted.

Comment: @0___________ *never hide pointers. Very bad.*  Function pointers excepted.  `typedef`'ing function pointers can be the only way to write comprehensible code involving function pointers.  Imagine a pointer to a function that takes a function pointer as an argument and returns another function pointer.  Try writing that without `typedef`.  Especially if the functions take a bunch of arguments.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `typedef` functions **not** pointers. Hiding function pointers is the same bad habit as hiding other pointers. If you `typedef` **functions** you will get much easier to read code: https://godbolt.org/z/c4crEovPz