# Two different types of asterisk locations for a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say you have this..

```
 int fry = 50;
```

Now wen making a pointer and referencing the value, the asterisk can be placed two different ways:

```
 int* d1 = &fry;
```

and...

```
 int *d1 = &fry;
```

I was wondering what the difference is and what situation it would be best to use each? Thanks!

Comment: There isn't really a difference.  But it doesn't mean some people won't argue on how many angels you can fit on the head of pin.

Comment: purely style. The only place it matters is when using `const int* const name`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/pointer-declarations-in-c-placement-of-the-asterisk and many more.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. You can even do `int*d1` and `int * d1`.

In my opinion, you should prefer `int *d1`: this choice has particular utility in avoiding confusion:

```
int* d1, d2;
int *d1, d2;
```

These statements both declare one integer and one pointer-to-integer. The first version looks quite misleading.

Comment: Best answer.  It's important to keep in mind that the `*` is attached to the variable and not the data type.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a difference in the two examples that you give. As to which you should use, follow the style of the code you're working in.

Note, though, that the * binds to the variable, not they type. Thus,

```
int *this_is_a_pointer, this_is_just_an_int;
```

and

```
int* this_is_a_pointer, this_is_just_an_int;
```

are the same. If you had need for something like this, I'd actually write either of the following to avoid any confusion

```
int* this_is_a_pointer;
int this_is_just_an_int;
```

or

```
int *this_is_a_pointer;
int this_is_just_an_int;
```

depending on the style that is being used.

Comment: So purely a preference of style. Thanks!