# What the difference between int *p and int* p

Tags: c++, pointers, int

I have seen many codes where they use int* to declare variables. I know `int*p` declares a variable of type integer which is a pointer. But what does `int* p` do?
for example :

```
int* x,y,z;
```

Does this mean all the three variables are pointers? Can we use int `*x,*y,*z` instead of this?

Comment: ***I know int *p declares a variable of type integer which is a pointer. ***

Comment: Originally in C the type was on the thing pointed to, so you would read it: "integer contents of p". The syntax reflected that when declaring multiple variables separated by commas. Straustrup said he felt the type was with the pointer rather than the contents which is better expressed `int* p` more like:"integer pointer to p". And this way of viewing the types is possible in every place **except** when you declare multiple variables separated by commas. That could not be changed due to backward compatibility issues. So  it is entirely notional and about how you view the types.

Comment: There is no functional difference.  Some folks prefer one and some the other (and some split the difference with `int * x;`).  The critical thing to understand is that `int* x,y,z;` declares one pointer and 2 ints, regardless of where spaces are placed around the `*`.

Comment: @Rohan `int *p` declares a variable of type pointer-to-integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placement of the asterisk in pointer declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-pointer-declarations)

Answer (score 5):

> What the difference between `int *p` and `int* p`?

Except where it's needed to separate tokens (which it isn't here), whitespace never affects the meaning of C++ code. Both have identical meanings (as to `int * p` and `int*p`); the spacing is purely a matter of taste.

> Does this mean all the three variables are pointers?

No, only the first is a pointer. In this case, the spacing is slightly misleading, so some would prefer to make the association clearer:

```
int *x, y, z;
```

or, better still, don't try to declare variables of multiple types in a single declaration:

```
int * x;
int y,z;
```

If you want them all to be pointers, then you have to specify it for each:

```
int *x, *y, *z;  // adjust spacing to taste
```

Comment: if you want all three as pointers, declare as:

int *x, *y, *z; and not as int *x, y, z; The later would declare x as integer pointer but y, z as int. Position of * should be before the variable (space optional)

Comment: @DebasishJana: Indeed; that's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to "look at" variable `p`:

- You can consider `p` as a variable of type `int*`.
- You can consider `*p` as a variable of type `int`.

Hence, some people would declare `int* p`, whereas others would declare `int *p`.

But the fact of the matter is that these two declarations are identical (the spaces are meaningless).

You can use either `p` as a pointer to an integer value, or `*p` as the actual pointed integer value.

Assuming that `p` is pointing to a valid memory address, and depending on access permissions:

- You can get (read) the pointed data, for example, `int c = *p`.
- You can set (write) the pointed data, for example, `*p = 5`.

---

When declaring several variables on the same line, the compiler assumes the type **without** the asterisk.

Therefore, with `int *x,y,z`, only `x` is regarded as an `int` pointer.

If you wish to have `y` and `z` regarded as `int` pointers, then you need to use `int *x,*y,*z`.

So using a space between the type and the asterisk is possibly a better coding-convention.

Personally, I always declare pointer variables in separate lines (one line per variable).

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Yep, I was just in the process of adding it (see updated answer).