# Pointer initialisation in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

In the C++ book I am reading. It gives the syntax for initialisation as

```
int *pInteger = NULL;
```

However it also showed the following as an example

```
int Age = 30;

int* pInteger = &Age;
```

Why is there a discrepancy? i.e. * after the int and * before the pInteger. Is the following correct?

```
int Age = 30;

int *pInteger = &Age;
```

Comment: What discrepancy are you referring to?

Comment: The 1st example initializes it to _nothing_. The 2nd example **also initializes** it but with a valid address.

Comment: @juanchopanza In the second, the * is  after the int. In the first, the * is in front of the pInteger...

Comment: Apparently this is not a discrepancy; there are different ways to initialize a pointer.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the initialization, that's part of the syntax of declaring a pointer. They're equivalent, different programmers have different styles.

Comment: The difference in white space is of no consequence (it's equivalent).

Comment: @Lost1 see [placement of the asterisk in pointer declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/180401/3953764)

Comment: It's like the difference between `x+ y` and `x +y`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I see, that is kind of what I was asking.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `int * pInteger = NULL;` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is generally a free-form language. You can use whitespace pretty much however you like. All of the following are equivalent:

```
int *foo1;
int* foo2;
int * foo3;
int*foo4;
```