# Pointer star location

Tags: c, pointers, code-formatting, gnu-indent

With GNU indent is there a way to put the "star" right after the type?

For example:

```
void* foo(int* a)
```

but keeping it near the var in a declaration like

```
int *a, b;
```

Comment: Don't mix pointers and non-pointers in a single declaration.  That avoids most of the issue.  The `*` denoting pointer is part of the declarator, which is the part after the type and storage classes and so on.

Comment: Are you open to using other code formatting tools? I don’t know much about Indent, but `clang-format` at least allows you to always put it to the left (I don’t think it allows switching based on context, though).

Comment: I've an Emacs macro that format the code calling indent so I think that I easly can switch to another command, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

C standard doesn't say anything about keeping `*` immediately after `type` or before `variable name`, both are fine.

```
int *ptr1, ptr2;/* valid, ptr1 is pointer variable, ptr2 is normal variable */
int* ptr1, ptr2;/* valid, ptr1 is pointer variable, ptr2 is normal variable */
```

Similarly in function declaration or definition for e.g

```
void* foo(int* a) { 
/*...*/
}
```

or

```
void* foo(int *a) { /* a is int pointer */ 
/*...*/
}
```

Read this [Placement of the asterisk in pointer declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-pointer-declarations)

Comment: So I can choose, perfect.
What are the option to have the first type of style?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't say how to configure GNU Indent to have the start in a specific place

Comment: Keep the `'*'` with the variable, avoid confusion, e.g. `char* a, b, c;` certainly does not declare 3 pointers. (1 pointer and 2 char) Much clearer as `char *a, b, c;`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: And one variable per declaration is clearer still: `char *a; char b; char c;` (or, at least, `char *a; char b, c;` so separate types are declared separately).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - no quarrel with that. (also there is no `gnu-indent` option for placement of the `'*'`)

Comment: oh ok, so neither an "external module"?

Comment: No, I just went through `man indent` and there is absolutely nothing that references the placement of the `'*'` -- sorry.

Comment: @RobertoAureli See this https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_chapter/indent_1.html#SEC10

Comment: I will add two cents. In C the style used in standards (e.g. [C99](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf) is `int *ptr;` as to denote, that the expression `*ptr` has the type of `int` (that was K&R intention). In C++ they use `int* ptr;`, see e.g.[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer).