# What is the difference between the ways of declaring a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

What changes between these two ways?

`int *ptr` and `int* ptr`

Both work the same way, but for my code or performance my program has difference?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a(5);
    int *ptr1 = &a;
    int* ptr2 = &a;

    cout << "a:    (0x" << hex << uppercase << (uintptr_t)&a << ") = " << dec << a << endl;
    cout << "ptr1: (0x" << hex << uppercase << (uintptr_t)ptr1 << ") = " << dec << *ptr1 << endl;
    cout << "ptr2: (0x" << hex << uppercase << (uintptr_t)ptr2 << ") = " << dec << *ptr2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a:    (0x61FE0C) = 5
ptr1: (0x61FE0C) = 5
ptr2: (0x61FE0C) = 5
```

Comment: the whitespace is ignored

Comment: duplicates: [Placement of the asterisk in pointer declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180401/995714), [Declaring pointers; asterisk on the left or right of the space between the type and name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660633/995714)

Comment: Both are the same. The real answer is "choose one, be consistent". As a personal thing, I tend to see `int *ptr1` as C-Style choice while `int* ptr1` as a C++ style choice. But look at the style guide of the project you are using.

Comment: Style, but in Java for instance you can write `int a[], b[]` or `int[] a,b` (same thing), but in C `int* a,b` declares `a` pointer but `b` is an int, thus I prefer to stick the star to the pointer variable, like `int *a,b` that I find more readable, and maybe less ambiguous for C beginners.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely nothing. Whitespace is ignored.

Where to align is a decision of [style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style), based on team conventions and rules (if any) or personal preference, and is mostly to improve the readability of the code. It doesn't change how the code is compiled.

Answer (score 2):

They're the same:

```
int a {5};
int *ptr1 = &a; // same as below
int* ptr2 = &a;
```

Not just for pointers but also for references:

```
int a {5};
int& b = a;
int &c = b; // same as above
int & d = a; // same
```

Answer (score 1):

The both declarations have the same meaning. You could consider even two more declarations

```
int *ptr1 = &a;
int* ptr2 = &a;
int * ptr3 = &a;
int*ptr4 = &a;
```

or

```
int*ptr4=&a;
```

The compiler can parse these records correctly without an ambiguity. The symbol `*` may be a part neither of an identifier nor of a keyword.

The difference between the records of these two declarations

```
int *ptr1 = &a;
int* ptr2 = &a;
```

lies in the semantic between declarators and type specifiers.

For example you may write

```
int ( *ptr ) = &a;
```

but you may not write

```
( int * ) ptr = &a;
```

Or you may write

```
int typedef *ptr;
```

but you may not write

```
int * typedef ptr;
```

So it is preferable to write

```
int *ptr1 = &a;
```

instead of

```
int* ptr2 = &a;
```

For example this declaration

```
int* ptrq, ptr2;
```

does not declare two pointers. Instead you need to write

```
int *ptr1, *ptr2;
```

Or if you have a pointer to an array like

```
int a[10];
```

then  you even can not use the combination `int*`. You have to write

```
int ( *ptr )[10] = &a;
```

Comment: Oh Vlad... You wrote "preferable" in a question about style... Rookie mistake :-D

Comment: @littleadv The mistake and an incorrect behavior is your comment.

Comment: Oh dude, lighten up, it's a good answer. Just invites a flamewar, but those are always fun