# typedef variable to pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Why list node is pointer type what's difference will be without pointer?

```c
typedef struct node {
    char data;
    struct node *nextptr;
} node_t;
    
typedef node_t *listnode;
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: this code  is in c language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: actually its not (typedef node_t *listnode;) this is for linked list why listnode is pointer type thats my question?

Comment: "why listnode is pointer type" because `typedef node_t* listnode` means "define `listnode` as a type-alias for `node_t*` (the `*` is part of the left-hand-side _source type_, not the right-hand-side type-alias name) (which is why I personally always keep the `*` on the left, not the right). [Also read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-pointer-declarations).

Answer (score 0):

it is pointer type because you have n elements, and for every element you now it data, and pointer for next element. n you may not know, so you use dynamic array of your structures. you can declare you your array using *. and after that you can give him memory. if you know n, it may be `typedef node_t listnode[n];`

Comment: but `typedef node_t *listnode;` is better

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic allocation of memory, you need a pointer to store the base address of memory space allotted. Thus declaring a pointer to the structure of type node_t helps you to go with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: so int is pointer type only because we can dynamically able to allocate space. And for every node memory of structure will be continuous.